# Error en el coontructor cuando lo llamo desde otro Jfram en java neatbeans

Tags: java, msql

tengo un problema con respecto al contructor.
en mi proyecto tengo 2 java class, una es la clase madre (libro) y una sub clase (novela).
cuando intento llamar a novela, desde el Jfram From (NovelaVista) me dice que el contructor esta mal hecho y cree uno nuevo.

esta es mi sub clase novela :

```
public class Novela extends Libro
{
    private String tipo;
    private String saga;
    private PreparedStatement ps;
    private Conexion CN;
    
    public Novela(Date diaIn, Date diafin, String reseña, String autor, String titulo, String tipo,String saga) {
        super(diaIn, diafin, reseña, autor, titulo);
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.saga = saga;
        ps = null;
        CN = new Conexion();
    }
    
    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }
    
    //gets y sets
    
     
    // conexion con base de datos
    private final String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO novelalibro (diaIn,diafin,reseña,autor,titulo,tipo,saga) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";    
    public int insertDatos(Date di, Date df, String res, String au, String tit,String tip, String sag) throws SQLException
    {
        try {
            ps = CN.getConexion().prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT);
            ps.setObject(1, di);
            ps.setObject(1, df);
            // el resto
            int resp = ps.executeUpdate(); 
            if (resp >0)
            // el resto
        return 0;
    }
```

segun yo esta correcto, (en la base de datos tuve que crear un tabla vista ya que no existe KEY en conjunto)

el error que me da en el JFam From es el:

> Contructor Novela in class Novela cannot applied to given types;
> required Date,Date,String,String,String,String,String found: no
> arguments reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in legth

no entiendo por que me dice eso, si están en el mismo orden.

hice algunos cambios en el codigo y ahora en en Jfram From esta asi:

````
    
    private void GuardarNovelaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent 
    evt) {   
    //dato
   //dato
   nova.insertDatos(di, df, res, au, tit, tip, saga);
   } catch (Exception e) {
   }
        ```
       
ahora no tengo errores, pero no guarda.
````

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro: *`found: no arguments`* y *`actual and formal argument lists differ in legth`*. No le estás pasando ningún argumento al constructor de `Novela`. ¿Podrías mostrar el código donde construyes la instancia de `Novela` pulsando en [edit]?

Comment: Está parte también está mal: `ps.setObject(1, di);`. Por cada signo `?` en la consulta preparada que tienes en `SQL_INSERT` debes setear un valor y debes ir aumentando el primer parámetro: 1,2,3... etc. Tienes 7 marcadores, debes setear 7 valores.

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que al pasar los argumentos en

```js
public Novela(Date diaIn, Date diafin, String reseña, String autor, String titulo, String tipo,String saga)
```

pueda que falte pasar las variables ps y CN